# Should both related models have Many-To-Many fields?

Tags: django, performance, database-design, many-to-many

I have two models, `FireEngines` and `Districts`,

`FireEngines` can choose any number of `Districts` it chooses. As a fire company grows it can choose to add more districts.

I'm not sure how to represent this in my Django app.

Since many `FireEngines` can have many `Districts`, and many `Districts` can be served by many `FireEngines`, clearly there is a Many-To-Many Relationship.

But I'm confused about how to write them.

Do I put a Many-to-Many relationship in each model?
For example

```
class FireEngine(models.Model):
     ....
     districts = models.ManyToManyField(District)
```

and

```
class District(models.Model):
     ....
     fireEngines = models.ManyToManyField(FireEngine)
```

or only one?

What happens if I want to know all the `FireEngine`s that serve a certain `District`? And what about if I want to know which `District`s are served by a certain `FireEngine`?

Comment: there is no def (it is class), you define m2m in one of the models, there is backward lookup available, add a `related_name` definition in the m2m and you can query with that name from the other model.

Comment: @petkostas Thanks I fixed the defs. But is it slow to use backward lookup all the time?

Comment: prefetch_related:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related

Comment: @Imray The Django is only describing what your database tables look like. It isn't setting up pointers that are going to be followed.